# How to use forms for each <TR> in the table? It is requirement to insert multiple submit buttons in a table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

Actually I would like to retrieve some data from the server and I need to display each products in a table along with a 'click to buy' button for each product. I tried to use FORM tag for every TR element in the table. But its not working. Can anyone share some ideas please?
I am using jsp and I retrieved data from the server using ajax. 
Everything works fine but button doesn't..

Comment: You can place a form inside a table cell `<td>`, not directly inside a row `<tr>` . Paste here the code you already have that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).